# Unable to set notifyDataSetChanged in Android

Tags: android, web-services, gridview

I have a case where I load a set of 10 images via WebService and and on further scrolling, I call upon the second WebService which load the next 10 images. I am able to load all the images from WebService but I am doing something silly that removes the first 10 images and re-assigns it with the next 10 images while calling the 2nd web service. I have tried notifyDataSetChanged() but it has no effect. The code is as follows :

**CODE :**

**MainActivty :**

```
new WebServicesClass().generateSampleData(); -->1st WebService
mGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScroll firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem +
                            " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount +
                            " totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
        // our handling
        if (!mHasRequestedMore) {

            System.out.println("Inside the requested more");
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onScroll lastInScreen - so load more");
                mHasRequestedMore = true;
                new WebServicesClass().onLoadMoreItems(); --> 2nd WebServiceCall
                mHasRequestedMore = false;
            }
        }
}
```

**WebServicesClass :**

**1st WebService :**

**onDoInBackGround :**

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://demo.bsetec.com/fancyclone/android/users/products?user_id=2&limit=0");

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet,
                        localContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                System.out.println("Buffered Reader " + reader.toString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag",
                        "Error converting sms response result " + e.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
            try {
                limit_for = 0;
                OpenHttpConnection(image_url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**OpenHttpConnection :**

```
public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String image_url)
                throws IOException {

            int response = -1;
            JSONObject jsonresponse;
            String first_image = null;

            try {
                jsonresponse = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.i("Inside OpenHttp", result);

                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject status = jsonresponse
                                .getJSONObject("status");

                        // looping through All Contacts

                        if (status != null) {

                            products = status.getJSONArray("products");

                            dreamt_product_list = status
                                    .getJSONArray("dreamit_products");

                            System.out.println("Dreamt Products list are "
                                    + dreamt_product_list.getJSONObject(0)
                                            .names());

                            System.out.println("The value of string limit is "
                                    + limit);



                            System.out.println("The limit_for value is "
                                    + limit_for);

                            for (int p = limit_for; p < load_limit; p++) {

                                System.out.println("Products names: "
                                        + products.getJSONObject(p).names());
                                System.out.println("Item Name "
                                        + products.getJSONObject(p).getString(
                                                "name"));
                                product_name = products.getJSONObject(p)
                                        .getString("name").toString();
                                cost = products.getJSONObject(p).getString("saleprice").toString();
                                product_id = products.getJSONObject(p)
                                        .getString("id");
                                username = products.getJSONObject(p).getString("username").toString();
                                System.out.println("Getstring: "
                                        + products.getJSONObject(p).getString(
                                                "images"));
                                String images_list = products.getJSONObject(p)
                                        .getString("images");

                                images_list = images_list.replaceAll("\"", "");

                                String regex = images_list.replaceAll(
                                        "\\[|\\]", "");

                                System.out
                                        .println("The images without bracket are "
                                                + regex);

                                for (String comma_token : regex.split(",")) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                                        System.out
                                                .println("First Image name is "
                                                        + comma_token);
                                        first_image = comma_token;
                                        System.out
                                                .println("Image in first image is "
                                                        + first_image);

                                    }
                                    break;

                                }

                                System.out.println("I am here");
                                image_url = "http://demo.bsetec.com/fancyclone/uploads/approved_items/"
                                        + first_image;

                                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                                    throw new IOException(
                                            "Not an HTTP connection");

                                try {

                                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                    httpConn.connect();

                                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                                        compressed_image = image;

                                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                        options.inPurgeable = true;
                                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                                        options.inSampleSize = 1;
                                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,
                                                null, options);
                                        // in.reset();

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                                }

                                item = new RowItem(image, product_name, cost,
                                        product_id, dream_status,username);
                                rowItems.add(item);



                            }
                            System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" + rowItems.size());

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out
                                .println("Caught Exception in the 2nd try block");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught exception");
            }

            System.out.println("Ending OpenHttpConnection");
            return in;
        }
```

**onPostExecuteMethod :**

```
    mAdapter = newDynamicHeightAdapter(MainActivity.getContext(),R.layout.repeat_items,rowItems);
   System.out.println("ADapter size: "+mAdapter.getCount());
   MainActivity.mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**2nd WebService :**

**onDoInBackGround :**

The code is **SAME** as the first doInBackGround().OpenHttpConnection is also the same.

**onPostExecuteMethod :**

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); -->Not working
```

When I call the WebService initially, it retrieves the first 10 images as it is supposed to do. But when the 2nd WebService is called at onScroll, then it **REPLACES** the initial 10 images with the 10 images obtained **FROM 2nd WEBSERVICE**. All I want to know is, how do I **UPDATE** it **WITHOUT REPLACING ?**  Any help will be much appreciated guys. I am happy to help you with any queries.

**UPDATE :**

```
rowItems.addAll(rowItems);
```

Is the above code valid ?

**NOTE :** I am using a external library named StaggeredGridView.

Comment: post the complete code in potExecute and doInBackground

Comment: Use rowItems.addAll(rowItemReceivedFromWS2);  
This will add new item received from WS2 to the `rowItem`, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will tell adapter to refresh the listview.

Comment: @GauravGupta, You mean the one obtained from WebService 1 ?

Comment: let me explain in answer.

Comment: Are you making `a new rowItem` when you hit service or `re-using` previous `rowItem`.

Comment: I am using item = new RowItem(...) at the 2nd web service doInBackGround. Same as the first one.

Comment: Do you mean the list object as rowItem or the object of RowItem which has get and set methods  ? FYI, item is the object of class name RowItem which has get and set methods for various parameters. And rowItems is the object of List<RowItem>.

Comment: And yes, I have created a new list object as second_rowItems and added all the contents to it in the 2nd Webservice and added the second_rowItems to the first one as you suggested. rowItems.addAll(second_rowItems);

Comment: rowItems.addAll(second_rowItems); seems to add only the second_rowItems to rowItems as it can be seen from its size. When I print the size of rowItems, then it prints only 10 where it should be 20. Why would this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the adapter.

```
YourAdapter adapter=(YourAdapter) mGridView.getAdapter();
adapter.addAll(rowItems);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this works fine

Comment: I believe this is supposed to be in 2nd WebServices's postExecute ?

Comment: ya. Basically put a check whether its a 2nd WebServices class then run this code.

Comment: may i know your adapter is extended by what?? is it BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter<Item>

Comment: I would suggest you to change it to ArrayAdapter<Item>, because there is a freedom to add items and notify the data changed in the gridview

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `collection` of objects to the adapter, in your case it is `rowItems`.

`OnScroll` you hit a Web service and receives and parse the contents. These new content should be put in separate new arraylist. Say it is `newRowContents`.

Now, you need to add newRowContent to original row content.

```
rowItems.addAll(newRowContent);
```

Your backing datasource is updated now, and your listview needs to be refresh now.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Your answer makes good sense but I am not able to load more. If I reach the last image in the first 10 images and scroll more then the 2nd Webservice gets called but it doesn't set it. I beleive the mistake might be somewhere in MainActivity while calling the 2nd Web Service. Any insights on this ?

Comment: Are you flushing first 10 images? Are you over writing new 10 images with old 10 images ?